# Service now rest API, get Incidents for Project

Tags: web-services, rest, servicenow

I have a Java application.

I want to get incidents, requirements, and all details from **[Service Now](http://www.servicenow.com/)** using its REST API.

From the [demo service now](https://demochannel.service-now.com/), I am trying to get the JSON. If I give a URL like following for a project with Project name, I am getting the Project details only.

```
https://demochannel.service-now.com/pm_project_list.do?JSONv2&sysparm_action=getRecords&displayvalue=all&displayvariables=true&sysparm_query=short_description=Demo%20project%20(small)
```

Based on this, I want to get incidents, requirements and other aspects what Service now provides.

If I give URL like

```
https://demochannel.service-now.com/incident.do?JSONv2&sysparm_action=getRecords&displayvalue=all&displayvariables=true
```

It will give all the incidents, which is more than 10000 in the demo. In both project and

It has system id, and number and all. From Project if I take sys_id and query incidents by sys_id, I am getting empty response.

I found only Project task under Project, and I think I can query project tasks by parent sys id.

How I can I relate the project and other aspects like incidents, requirements, change, resources, and all others and query them based on Project?

Comment: Voting to close, it sounds like you need to talk to ServiceNow, not the world in general :)

Comment: Needs to be looked at by 3rd-Party.

Comment: @Moo-Juice May be others would have done this. So I asked here. And others may want in future :)

Comment: And I agree with @iCode. It does not have to say "JAVA" or "C#".

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the REST API as opposed to the JSONv2 API: https://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=CSHelp:REST_API